# Foreach vs for loop in C#. Creation of new object is possible in for loop, but not possible in foreach loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

I have always wonder why you can create new object of class '**SomeClass**' in **for** loop, but you can't do the same in **foreach** loop.

The example is bellow:

```
SomeClass[] N = new SomeClass[10];

foreach (SomeClass i in N) 
{
   i = new SomeClass(); // Cannot assign to 'i' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'
}

for (int i = 0; i < N.Length; i++) 
{
   N[i] = new SomeClass(); // this is ok
}
```

Can anyone explain me this scenario?

Comment: see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` iteration loops are known as 'read-only contexts.'  You cannot assign to a variable in a read-only context.

For more info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/369xac69.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Foreach loop iterates over IEnumerable objects..

Internally the above code becomes

```
using(var enumerator=N.GetEnumerator())
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    enumerator.current=new SomeClass();//current is read only property so cant assign it
}
```

As stated above in comment [current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) property is a **read only** property of [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx)..So you cant assign anything to it